# "Cannot run program" when using Runtime.exec with spaces in program filename

Tags: java, process, ioexception, runtime.exec

I am using the below code to open the "sample.html' file.

```
String filename = "C:/sample.html";

String browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe";

Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + filename);

pc.waitFor();
```

However, I am getting the below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Could someone please help me figure this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about why the path is being reported incorrectly by the error message (i.e. "c:/Program" rather than "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")

Comment: browser + filename would be `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exeC:/sample.html`, notice any additional problems with that?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 4):

`Runtime.exec(String)` automatically splits the string at spaces, assuming the first token is the command name and the rest are command line parameters. Also you do not have a space between `browser` and `file`, although that is not the root cause of the problem.

It thinks you want to run "C:/Program" with two command line arguments:

1. "Files"
2. "(x86)/google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exeC:/sample.html"

Use [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) instead, that way you have full control over what is what:

```
 String[] command = new String[]{browser, filename};
 Runtime.exec(command);
```

Comment: it also need a space between `browser` and `file`, such as: `exec(browser +" "+ filename);`

Comment: @bluebrain Yes thank you; I didn't see `file` in the original version of the post. Updating now.

Comment: @Bohemian No, that's not true. [`Runtime.exec(String,String[],File)`](http://bit.ly/1e0IROx) (and therefore `Runtime.exec(String)` uses a `StringTokenizer` with default settings to split the command string into a command and parameters. `Runtime.exec("a b c")` attempts to run "a" with two parameters, "b" and "c".

Comment: @Bohemian Jason C is correct, check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29

Answer (score 3):

Stop using `Runtime.exec(String)` - the problem is in how it *processes* the single string input.

The error message indicates *how/where* it is failing: note that it stops after "C:/Program" (or, the first space). This indicates that exec parsed the string "incorrectly" and thus isn't even looking for the correct executable.

> Cannot run program "C:/Program"

Instead, consider the use of [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). While the usage is *still* system-dependent, ProcessBuilder allows separation of the executable file-name (and need to deal with it specially) and the arguments and does it's darnedest to invoke the target correctly.

```
String filename = "C:\\sample.html";
String browser = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(browser, filename);
// setup other options ..
// .. and run
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

From what I can tell, in Windows, ProcessBuilder will wraps the individual components in quotes; this can create a *different* problem when arguments contain quotes..

Comment: `Runtime.exec(String[])` is a similar alternative but +1 (if I didn't hit my limit), `ProcessBuilder` is another good option. As for args containing quotes; not sure because I didn't test, but argument quotes are platform-specific so I would presume that `ProcessBuilder` would do the necessary escaping required for the current platform, and would therefore work correctly on arguments with quotes.

Comment: @JasonC I honestly just forgot about `Runtime.exec(String[])` .. :>

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    String filename = "C:\\sample.html";
    String browser = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        runtime.exec(new String[] {browser, filename});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This does not work, as `Runtime.exec(String)` automatically splits the string at spaces to determine command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters must be passed separately:

```
Process pc = rTime.exec(new String[]{browser, filename});
```

Using `exec()` is not like using the command line - you can not use spaces to delimit the command from its parameters. Your attempt would try to execute a command whose path was the concatenation of the exec and the filename as one giant string.

Comment: No. There is no version of `Runtime.exec` that can accept two `String` parameters. My answer is correct. See [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: (As a new mod I would expect you to take extra care into researching answers, especially prior to downvoting, as your comments carry more weight than a normal user's would.)

Comment: @jasonc yes there is a version (answer edited - I thought it was varargs). See [`Runtime.exec(String[]`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D))

Comment: No. That takes `(String,String[])`, not `(String,String)`, and the second parameter is the environment. See also my comments to you on my answer; both the documentation and the OP's observed error demonstrate the automatic splitting at spaces of `exec(String)`.

Comment: @JasonC yes. sorted now. I'm using my iPhone: it's a little tricky to edit/lookup etc

Comment: If it's tricky then don't do it. Better to let others answer than give an incorrect answer. Please correct your answer and your comments on mine when you can. At the moment I have the only entirely correct answer here. And please do not do this again, it isn't OK. Don't make me start a flame war on meta. I didn't vote for you.