# java - open url in chrome browser only

Tags: java, browser, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an url, I am trying to open that url in web view of JavaFX but the content was not compatible with web view. It's only compatible to the chrome and firefox. So I would like to open that Url in chrome browser only instead of opening it in web view. is it possible?(I don't want to open it in default browser.)

I tried the below code but we got the error as "Cannot run program "chrome": error=2, No such file or directory".

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "Chrome", "http://goo.gl/EsomR0" });
```

thanks,

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414646/cannot-run-program-when-using-runtime-exec-with-spaces-in-program-filename

Answer (score 14):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start chrome http://goo.gl/EsomR0"});
```

This worked for me.

--
Edit:
Only worked on Windows

Comment: Thanks, I need a solution that will working in all the platforms

Comment: How to pass url parameters in this !? I have three parameters which needs to be passed but using this command only first parameter only going

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `chrome.exe` on Windows. On Linux this works for running Chromium:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "chromium-browser", "http://example.com/" });
```

Obviously it's not going to work for Chrome (or Windows), but we're talking about the principle. 
Another possibility is that Chrome may not be installed. Try running it from the command line. If it doesn't work there, it's not going to work in Java. Another problem could be that you capitalized "Chrome".

Comment: If chrome is not on your Path, you'll need to specify the whole thing. e.g.:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] 
{"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
"C:\tmp\somelocalpage.html"});

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following for android to open URL only in chrome and it worked for me:

```
"googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url
```