# Im trying to Write a java Program to connect to a remote server where my database is located and do a "mysqldump"

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect to my database on a server and create a MySql dump using java, but it results in:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" mysqldump   -h 10.10.104.1 -P 3XX6 -u xxxxxx -pXXXXX snappoint > backup.sql");
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump":
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: and please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414899/1531124 ... it is a bad idea to use Runtime exec. Also note: you understand that you are dumping the DB **over** the network by doing so? This means that your **complete** DB is transferred over the network? Depending on what you want to achieve, it might be more meaningful to dump on the server, compress the output, and transfer compressed files only for example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `mysqldump` is installed **locally**?

I'll explain - `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` runs on your local machine. This means all code executed inside it will run *on your machine*, and not on any remote site you are connecting to. 
So what it means is that every binary executed here must be installed on the machine running the code, and that is why you received this error.

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out 
The problem was that Runtime.getruntime().exec  //occurs on ur local machine so u need to install mysqldump on ur local machine and not on the server

Hopefully someone needs this someday

Comment: I suggest you simply accept the answer that lead you to this insight. Sure, taht answer is currently badly worded, but that is how SO works: you ask, and when somebody tells you the root cause, you accept that answer, instead of writing your own answer afterwards.

Comment: And yep, the other answer has been reworded, so you should definitely go ahead and accept that one!